# Find File that contain and execute delete

Tags: linux, grep

```
find . | grep '(00h'
```

The above is what I did to find file that contain the string (00h

A list of files was printed out when I execute.

How do  I add -delete to this code to make it delete what the list was printed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question would be this:

```
find . | grep '(00h' | xargs rm
```

However your initial command does not really make sense, which is why the above throws an error.

Instead use the `grep` command directly in a recursive manner:

```
grep -rl '(00h' | xargs rm
```

Note: you can also do this with the find utility, but the above is more simple.

Comment: xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: Ah, this is because your original statement does not really make sense. One minute...